# how can convert filter in spatial to frequency domain with out matlab function?

Tags: matlab, filter, frequency

I have several code in matlab that use filter in spatial mode and frequency mode. 
matlab code :

```
%% filtering in frequency domain
%% initial command
clc;clear all;close all;
%% filtering in spatial mode

    h1=[0  1 0
        1 -4 1
        0  1 0 ]
f=imread('images/Fig4.11(a).jpg');
if isrgb(f)
    f=rgb2gray(f);
else
    f=f;
end
gs=imfilter(f,h1); 

%% filtering in frequency mode
F=fft2(f);
[R,C]=size(f);
H1=fftshift(freqz2(h1,C,R)); %filter in frequency domain
gf=real(ifft2(H1.*F)); % filtering on image
gfb=gf/256; % normalized
%% print tag
figure;imshow(f);title('Original Image');
figure;imshow(gs);title('Filtering in Spatial Domain ');
figure;imshow(gfb);title('Filtering in Frequency Domain ');
```

how can use filter in frequency mode instead of use matlab function (freqz2(h1,C,R))
I wanna convert my filter in spatial to frequency domain (Fourier transform)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `freqz2` call. Just use `H1=fft2(h1);`

By the way, you can also change your if statement from this

```
if isrgb(f)
    f=rgb2gray(f);
else
    f=f;
end
```

to become

```
if isrgb(f)
    f=rgb2gray(f);
end
```

The line `f=f` is not needed.

Comment: tnx a lot, but I wanna write that, without matlab function. how dose it work(fft2 or reqz2). I wanna program of those function.

Comment: I wrote H1=fft2(h1,C,R); cuze the program with H1=fft2(h1); dosent work (show totally black image). why?

Comment: you have to zero pad h1 to make it the same size as f. Definitely do not use freqz2. It is not at all what you want.